# add UIBezierPath to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibezierpath

i have a UIView with layout constraint (width:400, height:180) and i want to add a bezier inside the view.

my bezier is this:

```
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

// origin, height | left border
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 20)];

// origin, height | left border
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(0, _donationView.frame.size.height)];

// height, width | bottom border
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(_donationView.frame.size.width , _donationView.frame.size.height)];

[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(_donationView.frame.size.width, 20)];

[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(_donationView.frame.size.width - 20, 20)];

[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(_donationView.frame.size.width - 30, 15)];

[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(_donationView.frame.size.width - 40, 20)];

[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 20)];

[bezierPath closePath];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[bezierPath fill];
[UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
[bezierPath stroke];
```

after creating bezier i pass to:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeView = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] initWithLayer:_donationView.layer];
[shapeView setPath:bezierPath.CGPath];

_donationView.layer.mask = shapeView;
```

but the bezier goes to this CGRect(0, 0, 240, 128);

how can i have a CGRect of (0,0,400, 180)?

thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing this too soon, before `donationView` has attained its final size. Thus, when you read off its `frame.size`, you are getting the wrong result. You need to postpone the addition of the mask until *after* layout has taken place.

You can also run into further issues if `donationView` is ever resized *later*. It is quite annoying that a mask layer (or any layer) doesn't get to participate in autolayout. So if `donationView` is resized, you will have to remove this mask and create a new mask with the correct size and add it *again*.